# Using server-sent-events after a res.render() in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I was looking for ways to notify the client that a time-intensive function has finished, but after i had already responded with a res.render().

User Teneff recommended me Server-sent-events particularly this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sse-express

In all the examples i have seen so far, people are not using sse with a res.render().
I tried to do so with this code:

```
app.post('/pst', sseExpress, function(req, res)
{ 
   var url = req.body.convo;
   res.render('error.ejs');
   res.sse('connected', 
     { welcomeMsg: 'Hello world!' }); 
});
```

but i received:

```
"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."
```

So is it possible to send a sse after a res.render()?

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible to send a sse after a res.render()?

No.

It doesn't make sense to anyway.

You are either making a regular request expecting a regular response (in which case you would use `res.render()` or you are making a request looking for SSEs using `let eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:80/updates');`, in which case all the responses to it should be through `res.sse()`.

Comment: Thanks! Then can i try another way? Can i do a res.render() and then use socketIO to send a message to the rendered page to the client that the task is done? (And this will unlock a hidden div in the rendered page with a link)

Comment: @user1584421  — You would have a similar timing issue.